# Transaction Does not working in php,mysql

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I was just trying transaction with php. But does not working. here is the code

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('users',$conn) or die (mysql_error());
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `login` (id ,username ,password ,isactive)VALUES (3,  "rtyer",  "edt6e4",  "y");';
$sql1 = 'INSERT INTO `user` (
            `f_name` ,
            `l_name` ,
            `age` ,
            `place` ,
            `loginid`
            )
            VALUES (
            3,  "dsgdhg",  "yuity",  45,  "fj",  3
            );';
mysql_query("SET autocommit = off");
mysql_query("BEGIN");
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
$result1 = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$result2 = mysql_query( $sql1, $conn );
if(!$result2)
{
mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
echo "transaction rolled back";
exit;
}
else
{
mysql_query("COMMIT");
echo "Database transaction was successful";
}
mysql_close($conn);
```

there is mistake in the sql1 so data is not inserting into `user` table but rollbacking from the `login` table. Its entering into the if block but rollback is not occuring. Whats the problem here?

Comment: see my answer the problem seems to be the semi-colon

Comment: try.. write values in inverted commas. and remove extra semi colons

Answer (score 0):

Delete the extra semi-colon at this line and use double quotes and single quotes on values:

`$sql = 'INSERT INTO`login`(id ,username ,password ,isactive)VALUES (3,  "rtyer",  "edt6e4",  "y");';`  <--- this part

Into this and do the same to $sql1

`$sql = "INSERT INTO login (id ,username ,password ,isactive)VALUES ('3',  'rtyer',  'edt6e4',  'y')";` <-- deleted semi-colon

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `user` (
            `f_name` ,
            `l_name` ,
            `age` ,
            `place` ,
            `loginid`
            )
            VALUES (
            '3',  'dsgdhg',  'yuity',  '45',  'fj',  '3'
            )";
```

Comment: @Salini try using double quots on "insert ...." then single quotes on values '3', 'dsgdhg' ... do it to $sql and $sql1. See my edit

Comment: yes i deleted the semi-colon inside single single quotes but not working and also changed quotes.

Comment: there does not using any loop. only that much code.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction will work only in InnoDB. here it was MyISAM.